# Change <form action> via JS

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, action

I have a submit button outside the form. There is no way to place it within the form.
I want to change the "action" attribute of the form via JS.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Excel Export" onclick="excel_export('form_input','page2_xlsx.php')" />
```

JS:

```
function excel_export($formname,$formaction)
{
    document.getElementsByName($formname)[0].formAction = $formaction;
    document.getElementsByName($formname)[0].submit();
}
```

But this doesn't change the formaction and the action-page is still page2.php

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when I saw the post.

It's

form.action instead of form.formAction